# Left join with Code First MVC 4 EF4.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, ef-code-first, left-join

I'm creating a system where users have some setting to do to complete their account, see below :

Tables:

### **SettingsTypes**

1. Id
2. Name

### **Settings**

1. Id
2. FkSettingTypeId
3. IsEmailActivated
4. IsSMSActivated
5. IntervalNotification

So the SettingsType table have these kind of value :

1. Be warned if time almost over
2. Be warned about offers in my categories
3. ...

Back into my MVC4 application I need to create a controller that will return every SettingsType with Setting to get a html table where user can choose if he want receive an email and sms for each SettingsType.

I use the Entity Framework 4.1 with CodeFirst and an ordinary page will return the table object like this :

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var settings = db.Settings.Include(s => s.SettingsType);
        return View(settings.ToList());
    }
```

The include statement make an inner join and do not return all the SettingsType I need associated with the Setting.

How can I write my code to do a left or right join and get the right model to pass into my views like that :

```
@model IEnumerable<TenderSystem.Models.Setting>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SettingsType.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsEmailActivated)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsSMSActivated)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IntervalNotification)
    </td>
</tr>}
```

I tried many thing like these link :

1. [Entity Framework Code First Left Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729280/entity-framework-code-first-left-join)
2. [Fluent API Samples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx)

But I can't achieve what I expect for.

To conclude, I also use the SQL to LINQ converter tool to convert my very easy SQL left join into LINQ and may be return the object I can use into my view but I got this error : Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Need your help to understand the right thing to do with this situation.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think the Include can just be the child's model name as a string under one of the constuctors.  Here is a link for EF5.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k("System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include");k(Include);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

or shortened...
http://bit.ly/SOEttF

I am using WebAPI so the return wants an IQueryable and this works for me.

```
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public IQueryable<Run> Runs()
    {
        var rx  = _contextProvider.Context.Runs
            .Include("RunOutlineItems")
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where(r => r.RunStatusId < 4);

        return rx;
    }
```

also check this answer 
[Join and Include in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416847/join-and-include-in-entity-framework)